# Доступ к файлам windows с ubuntu 11.04

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

Поставил себе вместе Windows 7 и Ubuntu 11.04. Порой нужно воспользоваться парочкой файлов с винды, когда сижу под линухой. Каждый раз перезагружать комп и заходить под виндой, когда понадобится какой нибудь фильм или песня геморно. Можно ли сидя под Linux получить доступ к файлам моей винды?

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить доступ к разделу с ntfs, mount.ntfs-3g в этом поможет

Comment: Имелось ввиду:    aptitude install ntfs-3gпосле этого если не хочется ковыряться с командой mount можно просто перезагрузиться, примонтированные разделы обычно попадают в директорию /media.

Comment: В ubuntu ntfs-3g вроде бы уже встроен.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu ты ставил второй, скорее всего, при установку нужно было поставить метку монтировать раздел винды(не форматировать), тогда она будет монтироватся автоматически(ну естественно и путь куда будет монтироваться типа, /mnt/sda1 , /media/windows  и.тп.)Сейчас два приемлимых варианта: 1. С терминала sudo mount /dev/название раздела с виндой скорее всего sda /mnt/какой нибудь каталог или без такого 2. В графическом режиме через средство работы с дисками(gparted) или наподобие, смонтируй раздел(разреши доступ к нему) 3. Убунта, как правило(если однодисковая) с ntfs работать не умеет, скачай с репозитрия что либо для работы с ними, как тебе написал человек в первом письме

PS У вообще, что вы находите в убунте, она ж тупая как пробка резиновая, нормальный линукс (мандрива, альт PCLinux, федора) подобных проблем не имееет(даже доходной паппи)

Answer (score 0):

если убунта установлена из винды то виндовую систему не будет видно, если установить убунту паралельно то она имеет полный доступ к файловой системе виндовс)

кстати убунту очень прокаченная система, ни с чем не надо париться, всё всаёт из коробки - даже прнинтер и сканер hp подцепились без всяких установок дров! UBUNTU-для людей!

Comment: Была для людей, пока не вышла 11.04, а за ней 11.10. С этого момента лично для меня это обычная винда для домохозяек. Да и в десятой версии в репозиториях некоторые пакеты не спешили обновляться.

Answer (score 0):

Откройте **Система - Администрирование - Дисковая утилита** и посмотрите, виден ли раздел с виндой. Если да, то смотрите путь к этому разделу, например это /dev/sdb1. В терминале последовательно выполняете

> sudo su
>
> cd /media
>
> mkdir Windows
>
> *gedit /etc/fstab*

и добавляете в открывшийся файл строку

> /dev/sdb1 /media/Windows  ntfs-3g rw  0   0

Естественно, там может быть и /dev/sda1 и что нибудь другое, зависит от подключения жестких дисков на материнке. Это всё для автоматического монтирования раздела при загрузке. В общем случае можно в меню "Переход" выбрать "Компьютер" и там примонтировать диск ручками, либо смонтировать его из дисковой утилиты, но через некоторое время это очень сильно достаёт и проще этот процесс автоматизировать.